# Manipulate one image into several

Tags: imagemagick, magick++

I'm working with the Magick++ API and I'm trying to figure out how do I read in one image, and perform two different kinds of effects and save each out into a different image. Right now what I'm doing is reading in an image and warp/distort it along a circle path and saving that new one (image-warped.ext). This works great. My next step now is to also create another image that's a mirror flop. So read in a 400x400 pixel image, flop it along the right edge so I end up with an image that's 800x400 and then save that out.

How do I do that with the same original image object I just read in? I can't imaging having to go back and reread the original image again, after all it's already in memory. Or am I mistaken?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that I can simply pass it:

```
Magick::Image originalFile;
originalFile.read("file.png");

Magick::Image clonedFile = originalFile;
```

At this point I have both originalFile and clonedFile. I can treat each one separate.

Source: http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html - second example down.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the CloneImage() function. Read it in, clone it, work on one and output, then work on the clone.

That's the way the command-line tools work too... [see here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#clone).

Comment: Hrm. I think I understand what you're saying. I'll have to play with it on the command line. However, ultimately I need to do this with the Magick++ API (through c++) so doing it on the command line isn't going to help me much, I don't think. I have a hard time translating command line arguments and options to the API.